# Issue document to open in edit mode using lotus Notes Cilent

Tags: lotus

this is link which i am using to open document in edit mode , but document is opening in read only mode. i check that there is no issue with author field.so can you suggest me what is the issue it might be.

Notes://CB10DEV@cbob/__85257C2F005410FE.nsf/0/8C2F729AF16F74DD85257C85007860B0?EditDocument

Comment: Just checked exactly this kind of link here: It works like a charm. Do you have any code in your QueryOpen / PostOpen / QueryModeChange / PostModeChange- events, that might prohibit opening in edit mode?

Comment: Thanx Torsten  
 but there is no code , is there issue with the xpage because it is opening xpage instead of form

Comment: That of course is very important information... Because THIS does not work for me as well... seems that XPage does not get URL- parameter...

Comment: So is there any option for edit document from notes ..??

Comment: You need to change your url: ...__85257C2F005410FE.nsf/NameOfXpage.xsp?OpenXPage&documentId=8C2F729AF16F74DD85257C85007860B0&action=editDocument

Comment: Sorry torsten it is not working ..

Comment: Thats a very exact description of an error...